# how to get dupes from table using group by and/or having

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have this table:

```
id | aux_id | name
------------------
1  | 22     | foo
2  | 22     | bar
3  | 19     | baz
```

How can I get this result, showing names that share an `aux_id` with at least one other record?

```
name
----
foo
bar
```

I know I need to use `GROUP BY` and/or `HAVING` but this isn't working:

```
SELECT name FROM my_table
GROUP BY aux_id
HAVING COUNT(aux_id) > 1
```

> Column 'name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: When you say you `know` you `need` to use `GROUP BY`, what do you mean?

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` are not the right constructs to do what you want.

Comment: sorry, I should have said "Someone told me to use GB and Having...."

Comment: They're wrong.  Use @GordonLinoff's answer.

Comment: Group By still could be used in fact. select * from myTable where aux_id in (select aux_id from myTable group by aux_id having count(*) > 1). You can see demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6a46/2

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `EXISTS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `exists`?

```
select t.name
from my_table t
where exists (select 1
              from my_table t2
              where t2.aux_id = t.aux_id and t2.name <> t.name
             );
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `exists` :

```
select t.name
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.aux_id = t.aux_id and t1.id <> t.id);
```

This will have a advantage to cover all columns if you want, without using `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, just for fun...

```
WITH
  duplication_counts AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY aux_id)   AS aux_id_occurrences
  FROM
    my_table
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  duplication_counts
WHERE
  aux_id_occurrences > 1
```

Comment: I think that is the same as what I wrote 4 min ago

Comment: @Sami Using `COUNT(*)` ensures all duplicate rows are returned, using `ROW_NUMBER()` ensures only one row is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Group by works IMHO (performance would not be good in large data as it would be with EXISTS):

```
select * from myTable 
where aux_id in 
  (select aux_id 
   from myTable 
   group by aux_id 
   having count(*) > 1)
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f6a46/2)

Comment: But performance of `IN()` usually collapses with large result sets.  At which point `EXISTS()` is often used instead.

Comment: @MatBailie, I didn't say anything about performance, I only said it works too (if you check the comments above there was a belief that it wouldn't).

Comment: In the comments there is a belief that it's not ***needed***.  *(There are alternatives, and mostly better ones, even so I've upvoted you and @GordonLinoff.)*

Comment: @MatBailie, Oh sorry I got that as wouldn't work, you are right.